# Segmentation fault 11 thread program

Tags: c, multithreading, algorithm, pointers

I'm having the error "Segmentation fault 11" with the following code :
I created a thread who give in parameters a struct.

I think the problem is in the declaration of the function `*MARIT`.

Sorry for my bad English I am French.

```
struct parametres {
        double *T;
int N; //taille
};

void *MARIT(struct parametres parametres)
{
int *somme =0;
float *moyenne = 0;
int i;
for(i = 0; i < parametres.N; i++)
*somme = *somme + parametres.T[i];
printf("somme : %d",somme);
*moyenne = (*somme/(parametres.N+0.0));
pthread_exit(moyenne);
}`


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
float temps;
clock_t t1, t2;
t1 = clock();
struct parametres params;
printf("Salut √† toi !\n");
printf("Donnez la taille du tableau :" );
scanf("%d", &params.N);
params.T = malloc( params.N * sizeof(double) );
int i = 0;
int nombre_aleatoire = 0;
for(i=0; i<params.N; i++){
nombre_aleatoire =  (rand() % 1000) + 1;
params.T[i]=nombre_aleatoire;
}
pthread_t arith,quadrat,cubi;
if(pthread_create(&arith, NULL, MARIT, (void*)&params) != 0)
{
perror("pthread_create");
exit(1);
}
double *result=0;
pthread_join(arith, (void**)&result);
printf("le resultat du thread : %f",result);

return 0;
}
```

I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: `void *MARIT(struct parametres parametres)
{` --> `void *MARIT(void* data)
{ struct parametres parametres = *data;`. Also, remove all the asterisks(`*`) before `somme` and `moyenne`.

Comment: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'void *(struct paramètres)' to paramètre of type 'void *(*)(void *)' At line "pthread_create"

Comment: Cool Guy, there is an error : initializing 'struct parametres' with an expression of incompatible type 'void' Thank you

Comment: Oh. Try `void *MARIT(void* data) { struct parametres parametres = *(struct parametres*)data;` then

Comment: It works but the error Segmentation Fault 11 still appear

Comment: Did you remove all the asterisk before `somme` and `moyenne`? Also, try making `moyenne` a `double` instead of a `float`. Don't forget to free the `malloc`ed memory after use by using `free(params.T);` at the end of the program in order to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: It gave me `pthread_exit(moyenne);` passing 'double' to parameter of incompatible type 'void*' Ty for your help

Comment: I've put an & at `pthread_exit(&moyenne)` my thread is created and exited but he gave me a wrong result (0 for the average)

Comment: Compile with debugger flags and run is through Valgrind, that tackles the problem most of the time

Comment: @FlorianSL Try `pthread_exit((void*)moyenne);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

First, the signature of `MARIT`. It must take a sinlge `void*`  parameter.

Second, `somme` and `moyenne` are declared as pointers, but you don't allocate any memory for them. This is what is causing the segfault.

Third, the return value must be a void pointer. That means that it must have the size of a pointer and the value it points to must persist past the call (returning the address of an automatic variable inside `MARIT` is not ok).

Fourth, `main` expects a double to be returned, so change the type of `moyenne`.

Fixing all three issues could be done like this:

```
void *MARIT(void *param)
{
    struct parametres *parametres = (struct parametres*)param;
    int somme =0;
    double moyenne = 0, *ret;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < parametres->N; i++)
        somme = somme + parametres->T[i];
    printf("somme : %d",somme);
    moyenne = (somme/(parametres->N+0.0));
    ret = malloc(sizeof ret);
    *ret = moyenne;
    pthread_exit(ret);
}
```

Note that, when the `main` function is done processing the retrun value it should `free` it. In this case, where the program ends right afterwards, freeing the memory is not really necessary.

You also need to change the printf in `main`:

```
printf("le resultat du thread : %f", *result);
```

Comment: Thank you, now it works but the thread don't return the fine answer for the average, it always return 0

Comment: @FlorianSL Added fix of a 4th issue in `MARIT` (type of `moyenne` should match type of `result` in `main`). Also, a small change in the `printf` in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *somme =0;

...

*somme = ... // segmentation fault here
```

because you declared somme as a pointer (a NULL pointer moreover), to a non-allocated memory. Solution: `int somme = 0;`

Same goes to the varible moyenne : `float moyenne = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

```
> SYNOPSIS
>        #include <pthread.h>
> 
>        int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
>                           void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

your function must have a signature like

```
void * start_routine (void *);
```

the moment that is wrong almost everything is undefined behavior.
and you must always allocate memory to a pointer before doing operations on space they are pointing to *somme and *moyenne are crashing for same reason. Though I am complete unaware of your choice of using pointers instead of normal variables.

```
  void *MARIT(void *arg)  // change <--here
      {
          struct parametres *parametres = (struct parametres *) arg;  // change <--here
          int *somme = malloc(sizeof(int)); // change <-- here
          float *moyenne =  malloc(sizeof(float)); // change <-- here

          int i;
          for(i = 0; i < parametres->N; i++)  // change <--here
              *somme = *somme + parametres->T[i];  // change <--here
          printf("somme : %d",somme);
          *moyenne = (*somme/(parametres->N+0.0));  // change <--here
          pthread_exit(moyenne);
      }`
```

Comment: Thank you, now it works but the thread don't return the fine answer for the average, it always return 0